# Mixamo Control rig problems

Tags: rigging, constraints, mixamo

I'm trying to convert a simple rig into a control rig with the [Mixamo Control Rig addon](https://www.substance3d.com/plugins/mixamo-in-blender/) but there is a lot I don't understand. Can someone help me with the following:

- Why knee "mollet d-tweak" is tweaking the wrong side when I move "pied d-ik"
- Why torse is still having scale tranformation when I move "neck" even whith a limit location constraint
- How to link the shoulder "DEF-epaule" to rest of body when I move "neck"
- How to limit the location of the shoulder "DEF-epaule" when I rotate the hips bone

[Download .blend](https://app.box.com/s/51nt78jvlsayfszdd03dxlqgpj8hls98)

Comment: Hi a33, i know you are pretty new here, but it would be very nice, if you could check the "checkmark" left of an answer if the answer to your question helped you. Thx. You can see your questions by clicking on your name, then questions: all "full" green questions were checked from you as "right" answers, everything else: unfortunately not.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVnfw.png thank you

Comment: and pls just focus on one question here, because the title is pretty short and can only address one topic. You can open as many questions as you want, but to make sure that all other users can benefit as well from your questions you should open a new question for every single problem you have, thank you

Comment: sorry i forgot about them i just checked the one missing

Comment: thanks for the edit i will be more careful on my other post